# Using JTextField to prompt for inout

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, readline

I'm trying to prompt for input from a JTextField.  That is, I want something akin to `String input = console().readLine()`, which waits until input has been given, and then uses that String.

Comment: Yes... and the question is? All I see is "Give me some cake!"

Answer (score 3):

Attach an `ActionListener` to the text field. `ActionEvent`s are generated, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, while the text field has the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a modal dialog to prompt the user. This will pause the application until the dialog is closed.

Check out [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for examples of how to customise a `JOptionPane`